# Javascript value not printing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a countdown timer in JS and style each digit (days, hours etc.) separately, I tried styling 'days' first, but it doesn't work while the default values do print (in the form).

Script (JS):

```
<script>
// set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date("Aug 15, 2019").getTime();

// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {

// find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
var current_date = new Date().getTime();
var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

// do some time calculations
days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

// format countdown string + set tag value
document.getElementById("days").value = days;
document.form1.hours.value = hours;
document.form1.minutes.value = minutes;
document.form1.seconds.value = seconds;

}, 1000);
</script>
```

HTML Body:

```
<body><div id="days"></div> 

<form name="form1"><p>Days <input type="text" name="days" value="0" size="3"> Hours
<input type="text"name="hours" value="0" size="4"> Minutes 
<input type="text" name="minutes" value="0" size="7"> Seconds 
<input type="text" name="seconds" value="0" size="7"> </p>
</form>
```

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Define "doesn't work."  The *styling* doesn't work?  There's no styling in the given code, so I wouldn't expect any styling to be applied to the markup.

Comment: What are you trying to style? The input inside the textbox? Or would you rather them be inside a span and style the span?

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle for your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is instead of put the value in an input box, put it in an element (span, div, or what-not).

For this you should use ".innerText", not ".value".

Here is what I think you're trying to achieve:

HTML:

Javascript:

```js
// set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date("Aug 15, 2019").getTime();

// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function() {

  // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
  var current_date = new Date().getTime();
  var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

  // do some time calculations
  days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
  seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

  hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
  seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

  minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
  seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

  // format countdown string + set tag value
  document.getElementById("days").innerText = days;
  document.getElementById("hours").innerText = hours;
  document.getElementById("minutes").innerText = minutes;
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerText = seconds;


}, 1000);
```

```html
<p>Days <span id="days"></span> Hours
  <span id="hours"></span> Minutes
  <span id="minutes"></span> Seconds
  <span id="seconds"></span> 
</p>
```

Here is the jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/fw69xfe2/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your div#days as output for your days value, you'd use `document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = days;` instead of your `document.getElementById("days").value = days;`

Answer (score -1):

you need to give the id attribute to your 1st input field, currently it have only name attribute. And you are trying to get the input field using it id in JavaScript. Change your html to this:

```
<form name="form1"><p>Days <input type="text" id="days" value="0" size="3"> Hours
<input type="text" name="hours" value="0" size="4"> Minutes 
<input type="text" name="minutes" value="0" size="7"> Seconds 
<input type="text" name="seconds" value="0" size="7"> </p>
</form>
```

Comment: my problem is the countdown timer is working with the form & input fields, but i want to use it with a div so i can style each digit separately.